# Scala: divide strings

Tags: string, scala

The title sounds a bit crazy but having the * function for java.lang.String in Scala (`"a" * 3 = "aaa"`), why don't we have a / function so that `"aaa" / "a" = 3` ?

Cheers
Parsa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the thinking. I'll answer with a question: why isn't there - function when we have a + function?

```
implicit def strDivider(s:String) = new {
  def /(q:String): Int = s.grouped(q.length).takeWhile(_ == q).size
}

scala> "aaa" / "a"
res0: Int = 3

scala> "abc" / "x"
res1: Int = 0

scala> "aaa" / "aa"
res2: Int = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Neither one makes sense. I got interested in that while thinking of a stupid way of removing extra whitespace from a document.

Answer (score 2):

Such an operation seems a bit odd. What would it mean to divide `"abc" / "x"`? The [`String.split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function seems more general purpose and useful here.

Answer (score 2):

You could also divide `String`s by `Int`s:

```
def divide(s: String, i: Int): (String,String) = {
  require(i>0)
  val Pattern = ("(.+)" + """\1""" * i + "(.*)").r
  val Pattern(q, r) = s
  (q,r)
}

assert(divide("aaa", 3) == ("a", ""))
assert(divide("aaaa", 3) == ("a", "a"))
assert(divide("abababc", 3) == ("ab", "c"))
assert(divide("abc", 1) == ("abc", ""))
assert(divide("foobar", 3) == ("", "foobar"))
```

Answer (score 0):

a construct like `"a" * 3` is used for things like creating separators when printing output to stdout so you can do `"-" * 72` instead of typing 72 hyphens on a line.  I don't see what benefit you could get from dividing though.